# How to add a working scroll side bar to a JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am currently working on a program which includes having a JTable which contains several sections of data. However just like most times i assume having no scroll bar on the side means that I am missing a lof of the data which I am trying to show. I have attemped to create a scroll bar in several different ways, including full reworks of my JTable set up, however that just ended up breaking my program in other ways.

Below I have attached a copy of the code which is resposnible for the filling of the JTable with data and for the creating of the frame and the jtable it self.

```
    public void create_frame3() {
        frame3 = new JFrame("SGD");
        frame3.setSize(250,250);
        frame3.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame3.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame3.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame3.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
        home2 = new JButton("Home2");
        home2.setBounds(20,20,100,50);
        inst = new JButton("insert");
        inst.setBounds(60,60,100,50);
        frame3.getContentPane().add(home2);
        frame3.getContentPane().add(inst);
        finance_app obj=new finance_app();      
        home2.addActionListener(obj);
        inst.addActionListener(obj);
        balSGD = new JLabel("Bal:"+calculateBal(arrlistW, arrlistD));
        balSGD.setBounds(50,100,100,50);
        frame3.getContentPane().add(balSGD);
    //the point at which the table is created 
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        SGDtb = new JTable();
        SGDtb.setBounds(195, 15, 270, 260);
        JScrollPane SGDjs = new JScrollPane(SGDtb);
        SGDjs.setVisible(true);
        SGDtb.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        panel.add(SGDjs);
        frame3.add(panel);
        frame3.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SGDtb.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(420,63));
        SGDtb.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        frame3.getContentPane().add(SGDtb);
    //method used for adding data 
        addRowtoSGDJTable();
        frame3.setVisible(true);
    }
```

```
    //Specific method used to add the rows to the table
    public void addRowtoSGDJTable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) SGDtb.getModel();
        Object[]columnsName = new Object[4];
        columnsName[0] = "TransactionID";
        columnsName[1] = "AccountID";
        columnsName[2] = "Amount";
        columnsName[3] = "Description";
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
        Object[] Data = new Object[4];
        for(int x=0;x<transaction.size();x++) {
            Data[0] = transaction.get(x).getTransactionID();
            Data[1] = transaction.get(x).getAccountID();
            Data[2] = transaction.get(x).getTransactions();
            Data[3] = transaction.get(x).getDescription();
            model.addRow(Data);
        }
```

I have attempted to use the JScrollPane and the JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF however that method of adding the table did not work.

Comment: All the `setBounds` and `setLayout(null)` is working against you - start by taking the time to learn and understand the layout system in Swing - [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

All the `setBounds` and `setLayout(null)` is working against you - start by taking the time to learn and understand the layout system in Swing - [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

## Why?

Because this is what your code produces on my system...

[image]

## The "compounding" cause...

Using `null` layouts is the primary reasons for your issues, but...

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
SGDtb = new JTable();
SGDtb.setBounds(195, 15, 270, 260);
JScrollPane SGDjs = new JScrollPane(SGDtb);
SGDjs.setVisible(true);
SGDtb.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
panel.add(SGDjs);
```

`panel` is using a `FlowLayout` by default, so my guess is it's attempting to honour the `preferredSize` of the `SGDjs` scroll pane, but you've ignored that and simply done what ever you want.

And while I'm on the subject, you should take the time to learn and use the established [coding conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) it will make it easier for other people to read your code ... and for you to read theirs.

## A possible solution...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel actionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.ipady = 16;
            gbc.ipadx = 16;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            actionPane.add(new JButton("Home"), gbc);
            actionPane.add(new JButton("Insert"), gbc);

            // This could actually be managed seperatly, maybe in the `SOUTH`
            // position of the `BorderLayout`
            gbc.ipady = 0;
            gbc.ipadx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = gbc.PAGE_END;
            actionPane.add(new JLabel("Bal: 0"), gbc);

            add(actionPane, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

            add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(createTableModel())));
        }

        public TableModel createTableModel() {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            Object[] columnsName = new Object[4];
            columnsName[0] = "TransactionID";
            columnsName[1] = "AccountID";
            columnsName[2] = "Amount";
            columnsName[3] = "Description";
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                Object[] Data = new Object[4];
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    Data[x] = x + "x" + y;
                }
                model.addRow(Data);
            }
            return model;
        }
    }
}
```